# Extract number from a string using a pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have strings like :

```
's3://bukcet_name/tables/name=moonlight/land/timestamp=2020-06-25 01:00:23.180745/year=2019/month=5'
```

And from it I would like to obtain a tuple contain the year value and the month value as first and second element of my tuple.

```
('2019', '5')
```

For now I did this :

```
([elem.split('=')[-1:][0] for elem in part[0].split('/')[-2:]][0], [elem.split('=')[-1:][0] for elem in part[0].split('/')[-2:]][1])
```

It isn't very elegant, how could I do better ?

Comment: consider using the [re package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for python with all its functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use, [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) along with the given `regex` pattern:

```
import re
matches = re.findall(r'(?i)/year=(\d+)/month=(\d+)', string)
```

Result:

```
# print(matches)
[('2019', '5')]
```

Test the `regex` pattern [`here`](https://regex101.com/r/hPjHeA/1).

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps regular expressions could do it. I would use regular expressions to capture the strings 'year=2019' and 'month=5' then return the item at index [-1] by splitting these two with the character '='. Hold on, let me open up my Sublime and try to write actual code which suits your specific case.

```
import re  
search_string = 's3://bukcet_name/tables/name=moonlight/land/timestamp=2020-06-25 01:00:23.180745/year=2019/month=5'  
string1 = re.findall(r'year=\d+', search_string)  
string2 = re.findall(r'month=\d+', search_string)  
result = (string1[0].split('=')[-1], string2[0].split('=')[-1]) print(result)
```

Comment: `import re

search_string = 's3://bukcet_name/tables/name=moonlight/land/timestamp=2020-06-25 01:00:23.180745/year=2019/month=5'

string1 = re.findall(r'year=\d+', search_string)

string2 = re.findall(r'month=\d+', search_string)

result = (string1[0].split('=')[-1], string2[0].split('=')[-1])
print(result)`

Hope it helps.